# Repeated measures correlation in SPSS

Tags: correlation, repeated-measures, spss

I am trying to look at the correlation between 2 variables, in a clinical sample, measured across 3 time points. Unfortunately, the sample is relatively small about 107 at baseline but across 4 groups, and with a large drop out rate, so only 74 at the final follow up. I initially looked at the correlation at each time point, but was hoping to increase the power (and the accuracy of the estimation) by combining the time points.  I found a nice article re how to do so in R (Bakdash & Marusich, Frontiers in Psychology, 2017), but I am not familiar with R, so was looking for something similar for SPSS.  I have tried running a linear mixed model, but get an error message that there are not enough observations for the number of parameters (which I am interpreting as the sample size is too small/ too many drop outs).  Can anyone assist with a way to run repeated measures correlation in SPSS?  Thank you!

Comment: How did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here's link to running rmcorr in SPSS: https://osf.io/4p3x6/
This file: rmcorr_SPSS (not recommended).zip

We don't recommend it because there's no easy way to visualize the model.

We're working on a web-based version of rmcorr in Shiny.